# Old brain inside young body

Tags: science-based, anatomy

You are 70 years old but you look 50, this because you have always maintained good health, mentally and physically.

After experimenting with various clones before, you decide it's time for you to have a brain transplant.

Doctors will put your brain inside a 17 years old clone of you.

Does this process lenghten your life or will you die anyway after a few years because your brain is old?

Comment: If you had young organs, you're not going to die of organ failure. Heart disease, cirrhosis, these are things your scheme fixes. But the brain does (or at least can) age, so this isn't an immortality scheme. It probably is a viable life extension scheme for some people.

Comment: Depends on WHY are you dying. Will help against heart attack, likely help against cancer, won't help against Alzheimer's.

Comment: Futurama experimented with this. Turns out their old folks prefer an invincible robot body over a young, sexy flesh body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a "fresher" body will not impact the effect of time on the "old" brain.

Neurons in particular do not regenerate, thus every single neuron will have already 70 years of usage on its history.

This will mean that the character will have a senile brain, more prone to aging issues typical of an old human, plus slower reflexes (which are probably more dangerous on a 17 years old body).